# Will a Sitemap in localhost create duplicate content issue?

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

For my Wordpress.org site I use the Google Sitemap Generator plugin by Arne B. While in localhost I activated the plugin and it works.

I usually update my website in localhost and then upload the database to my webhost. So now I am wondering if Google search results will now enter both urls below?? Reason I am asking is because I am afraid Google will consider this as duplicate content.

http://127.0.0.1/beef-recipe-1/
http://www.actual-website.com/beef-recipe-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google can't access your localhost (127.0.0.1) so it will most likely ignore those URL's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid of the above situation the best thing you can do is to delete all the previous sitemaps and re-generate a new one while your site is online. By going to Google's webmasters tools Resubmit the sitemap if necessary and crawl your websites main domain link for e.g: mydomainname.com and let Google crawl all direct links from associated to the homepage.

This way you will not lose rankings on Google while it may become a helping factor to your website.

Cheers!